# add a line as a first OR second line of a file, depending on content

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to add a line as a first line of many files, unless the first line of a file is a shebang, in which case it should be the second.

Comment: post that line at first

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest didn't get you

Comment: again: *I want to add a line* - what line? post it. We should check if the line contains special chars

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest does it matter? Say, `# inspected by DK`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest OK I see what you mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do it... e.g.

```
sed '1!b
/^#!/a\
one_line_text
//!i\
one_line_text' infile
```

Note that backslashes (if any) in your line have to be escaped (e.g. `\` becomes `\\`).
This won't edit empty files. Also, this won't edit the file in-place. Consult your `sed` manual to see if it supports `-i` to edit the file in-place (and check the syntax of that option).

Comment: neat, thanks! works well combined with `-i` and `find`

Comment: Instead of repeating the line you could skip the shebang line and always insert with `/^#!/n;i\` ...

Comment: @Philippos - I know ;) (check the edit history). That's actually cool but _there's a problem_: `n` will branch to end of script if executed on the last line which means that if you had a file with only one line and that line was a shebang, the code wouldn't work as expected.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't see that. And we surely don't want to fail on scripts consisting of only a shebang line. (-;

Answer (score 2):

In below script if 1st line  is shebang line then it will insert new content in 2 line
Otherwise it will insert content in 1st line

Tested and worked fine

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ `awk 'NR==1 && $1 == "#!/bin/bash" {print $1}' file` == "#!/bin/bash" ]]
then
sed '2i content' file
else
sed '1i content' l.txt
fi
```

Comment: Cool. Note that I am interested in *any* shebang, i.e. the first line starting with `#!`.
You could also use `head -1 file | grep "^#!"` and test for the exit status (0 for match, 1 for no match)